# Scrolling div inside absolute positioned parent

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute positioned div and inside I have another div with content bigger than the parent. I need the child div to have a vertical scroll but my attempts are not workin. I need to do this without js. This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="allow-scroll">
         ---CONTENT---
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.allow-scroll{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%:
}
```

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zasnj08z/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just one small error in your css.

The last line `height: 100%:` have a : at the end. Remove the colon and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you have overflow: hidden on the the parent

simply change it to

```
overflow: scroll
```

See here on your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zasnj08z/3/

Also - you don't need overflow scroll on the child, as it is the parent container that you want to scroll. Changed that in the fiddle as well.

Comment: This is a valid solution, but the other one is better for me, since I need the parent to have overflow hidden (not related to this issue)